# Problem with Parenting Mesh to Armature

Tags: rigging, armature, parent

I am trying to parent a mesh to an armature (following an online tutorial). The top picture is before I parent the mesh, the bottom picture is after I parent the mesh.

[image]

[image]

The steps I took to parent the mesh:

1. Select the all the bones in Pose Mode
2. Select the mesh, which takes me to Object Mode.
3. Shift select the armature.
4. Ctr + P, select Armature Deform with Automatic Weights/Empty Groups (both options gave the same resulting deformation.

In the tutorial, when the guy did the same steps his mesh did not deform like mine did. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your bones might be moved in the pose mode. To reset all the bones do the following.

- Make sure you are in pose mode
- Select all the bones
- press Alt + G, Alt + R, Alt + S to reset position, rotation and scale respectively.

Without more information than you gave in those screenshots, I can't really help any more. There might be some issues if you used a mirror modifier. (because then you need to name your bones with .r (right) and .l (left) correctly.

Comment: You are right, my armature was not in its rest pose which distorted the mesh. I reset my armature to its rest pose and it worked perfectly. Thanks!